# Showing error while refreshing modification in opencart

Tags: opencart

I am creating a site using `opencart 2.1.0.2`. I have installed the theme *Journal*. But when I am refreshing the modification it shows the following error:

> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/rakeshnb/public_html/open_cart/system/modification/system/engine/action.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/rakeshnb/public_html/open_cart/admin/controller/extension/modification.php
>   on line 408

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the directory exists in your opencart

```
/home/rakeshnb/public_html/open_cart/system/modification/
```

If so, try to delegate writing privileges to the web server user (usually it is www-data) for the directory and its content. You could try to set 777 rights and see if it helps. But don't forget to reduce access rights after that for security reasons.

Comment: directory is not exist but a modification.xml file exists

Answer (score 0):

Check the line in your **config.php** and **admin/config.php**:
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', DIR_SYSTEM.'**storage/modification**/');

Be careful, that in "opencart 2.1.0.2." the modified files are located in "system/storage/modification/" folder, not in the "modification".

It works for me. (the path was incorrect)